# Unable to mount current directory in docker image

Tags: docker, clojure

I am trying to run the following command:

`docker run -it -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app clojure lein uberjar`

Which is supposed to mount my current directory in the docker image and run `lein uberjar`. I got this command from: https://hub.docker.com/_/clojure/

When I run the command I get the following output:

`Couldn't find project.clj, which is needed for uberjar`

I do have a `project.clj` file in my local directory. When I go in the image it's clear that my local directory is not present in the image:

```
$ docker run -it -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app clojure
root@b8749c8ff93d:/usr/src/app# ls
root@b8749c8ff93d:/usr/src/app#
```

Any idea why my working directory is not being mounted in the image?

Comment: What is your host? Mac, Windows, Linux? What is your version of docker? Are you using boot2docker? Hyper-v?

Comment: and what does `echo $PWD` output?

Comment: This is on a Mac host and `echo $PWD` prints my working directory where my app is.

Comment: I have the same issue with node app